# Better way to write a WHERE clause with multiple <> conditions from same object

Tags: sql, excel, openedge, progress-db

I have built a statement to return the sizes for an component attached to the order. The issue i have is the query returns all components on the order such as delivery and packing which are irrelevant to me. All together there is over 45 components that i am not interested in seeing. To exclude these i have put into there `WHERE` clause everything i don't want to see. My problem is i feel this isn't the best way for me to approach with multiple `AND`'s listing each and every one.

To save the hassle i have put the main query below and only a portion of the where clause

```
SELECT

Job_0.JobJobNumber AS 'Job Number'
,Job_0.JobEstimateNumber AS 'Estimate Number'
,Component_0.CooComponentDescription AS 'Component'
,Component_0.CooMfsDescription AS 'Finished Size'
,Component_0.CooDownSize AS 'Down Size'
,Component_0.CooAcrossSize AS 'Across Size'
,Component_0.CooDownFactor AS 'Down Gap'
,Component_0.CooAcrossFactor AS 'Across Gap'
,MasterWorkingSize_0.MwsDescription AS 'Working Size'
,MasterWorkingSize_0.MwsMinimumWidth AS 'Width'
,MasterWorkingSize_0.MwsMinimumLength AS 'Length'

FROM
SBS.PUB.Job Job_0
JOIN SBS.PUB.Component Component_0 ON Job_0.JobID = Component_0.JobID
JOIN SBS.PUB.WorkingSize Workingsize_0 ON Job_0.JobID = WorkingSize_0.JobID
JOIN SBS.PUB.MasterWorkingSize MasterWorkingSize_0 ON WorkingSize_0.MasterworkingsizeID = MasterWorkingSize_0.MasterworkingsizeID

WHERE

Job_0.JobID > 254677392
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> 'Packing'
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> 'Delivery'
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Packing in 1,000s
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Finish Pad of Sets
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Part Outsourced
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Finishing Booklets
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Packing - band in 50s
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Small Job Uplift £10
AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <> Packing band in 50s
```

I was wondering other than what i have done above is there a better way in which i could nest these? Much like you can do in a `CASE WHEN` statement. what i hope to see is something like `AND Component_0.CooComponentDescription <>('Packing', 'Delivery', Packing in 1,000s,etc,etc)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `not in`:

```
Component_0.CooComponentDescription not in ('Packing', 'Delivery', 'Packing in 1,000s', etc, etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use would be to create a new table with a column that lists your exclusions, then use:

```
    SELECT columns
       FROM SBS.PUB.Job Job_0
       JOIN SBS.PUB.Component Component_0 ON Job_0.JobID = Component_0.JobID
       LEFT JOIN ExcludeComponent exc ON exc.CooComponentDescription = Component_0.CooComponentDescription
       WHERE exc.CooComponentDescription IS NULL
```

Then just populate `ExcludeComponent.CooComponentDescription1` with your list of 45 items. The advantage here is that this is more dynamic than putting all the terms in your query.